# Cannot override class RuleProductPricesPersistor in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, error, overrides, preference

I'm trying to override following class

> Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Indexer\RuleProductPricesPersistor

Using below code

```
<preference for="Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Indexer\RuleProductPricesPersistor"
                type="Vendor\Module\Model\Indexer\RuleProductPricesPersistor" />
```

But I'm getting following error

> Type Error occurred when creating object:
> Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Indexer\ReindexRuleProductPrice, Argument 5
> passed to
> Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Indexer\ReindexRuleProductPrice::__construct()
> must be an instance of
> Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Indexer\RuleProductPricesPersistor, instance
> of Vendor\Module\Model\Indexer\RuleProductPricesPersistor given,
> called in
> /var/www/html/MagentoCE230/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php
> on line 116 [] []

I tried to clear **generation** folder and also ran `setup:di:compile` command. But it didn't work.

Comment: please add `Vendor\Module\Model\Indexer\RuleProductPricesPersistor.php` code Here

Comment: are you trying to do a plugin or over write/preference? also can you add your construct method to the question

Answer (score 0):

```
Vendor\Module\Model\Indexer\RuleProductPricesPersistor.php
```

Your child class should be like this

```
<?PHP

 use Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Indexer\IndexerTableSwapperInterface as TableSwapper;
 use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Indexer\ActiveTableSwitcher;
 use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class RuleProductPricesPersistor extends \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Indexer\RuleProductPricesPersistor
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime $dateFormat,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        ActiveTableSwitcher $activeTableSwitcher,
        TableSwapper $tableSwapper = null
    ) {
        parent:: __construct($dateFormat ,$resource , $activeTableSwitcher, $tableSwapper ;);
    }

    // add overrided Functions Here 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `RuleProductPricesPersistor.php` code must look like this.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Indexer;

use Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Indexer\IndexerTableSwapperInterface as TableSwapper;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Indexer\ActiveTableSwitcher;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class RuleProductPricesPersistor extends \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Indexer\RuleProductPricesPersistor
{
   public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime $dateFormat,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        ActiveTableSwitcher $activeTableSwitcher,
        TableSwapper $tableSwapper = null
    ) {
        parent:: __construct($dateFormat ,$resource , $activeTableSwitcher, $tableSwapper);
    }
}
```